# iOS - Motion Usage Permission

Tags: here-api

I'm Using HereMaps 3.8.0 for iOS. While launching the application I could see the app asking for permission Location Services which is expected, but it is also requesting Motion Usage Permission. Please let me know why HereMaps is looking for Motion Usage permission and what does Motion Usage provides that Location Services doesn't provide already.

Answer (score 1):

All HERE iOS SDK apps must have these declaration entries for the App Store submission process. App users are only prompted for the appropriate data access if your app uses the relevant HERE SDK feature.

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>This is needed to determine your current location</string>
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>This is needed for the LiveSight augmented reality feature</string>
<key>NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key>
<string>This is needed for the Bluetooth-based indoor positioning feature</string>
<key>NSMotionUsageDescription</key>
<string>This is needed for the indoor positioning feature</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>This is needed to determine your current location</string>
```